# Move Azure database from one account to another acount in Azure

Tags: azure

I have two Azure accounts, A and B

I have a sql server database created under subscription of Account A.

I want to move this sql server database to subscription of Account B.

Comment: Is this Azure SQL or full instance of SQL server on a VM in Azure?

Comment: I found that the support team for azure is very helpful.  They might be able to offer a better solution.  Depending on the size you may want to avoid transmission costs of a typical database copy.

Comment: @JoeC there are no transmission costs when staying within the same region.

Comment: @Kyle this is Azure SQL,  it is not attached to any VM.

Comment: Sorry, my description was not very clear,  I have just edited it to make it clear.

Comment: By Account you mean different directories? (tenants) I am currently facing the same issue. the suggestion below from @hawbsl is good but I am not sure if it is the best way if you have a huge database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things that might help:

1. [Moving resources between subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources)
2. Subscription ownership transfer (to a different billing account)

I don't know anything about the latter, so unless somebody else has tips, it might be best to contact Support, if that's what you need.

In order to move resources between subscriptions, you'll need to make sure:

1. Both source and target subscriptions need to be in the same directory
2. One user account must have access to create and delete resources in both subscriptions
3. You need to move all SQL databases on that server at once

There may be other requirements, but those are the main ones I suspect you'll hit.

If subscriptions are in different directories, you can move the SQL server to a temporary, trial subscription, then move that subscription to the target directory (from the old portal), and finish the move in the new portal using the target directory.

If you're moving resources between organizations that use AAD accounts, you'll likely need to grant a Microsoft Account (e.g. outlook.com) access to each subscription and perform the actual move operation with that user. Don't forget to delete the subscription and remove the temporary user account from both subscriptions and directories after you finish the move.

Hopefully, that should be it. Of course, you could always just create a backup and restore that to a new server :-P

Answer (score 5):

You can do it all in SQL Server Management Studio

1. Connect to both Azure accounts in SSMS.

[image]

2. Right click on the *source* database and do **Tasks** -> **Export data tier application**
3. Save as a .bacpac file to your local disk
4. In the *target* connection, go to **Databases**, right click and choose **Import data tier application**
5. Choose **Import from local disk** and browse to the .bacpac file you just created

Comment: I've had error "Unable to connect to master or target server you must have a user with the same password" when trying to import `.bacpac` to Azure. Had to import database to localhost and then use [Data Migration Assistant](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/datamigration/dma/) tool for importing to another Azure account.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way similar to what hawbsl has described. However instead of exporting data tier application to local disk, export it to azure blob storage.

So export database in Account A to azure blob storage in Account B:

[image]

Then in Account B go to your sql server and click import database:

[image]

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import) will describe how to import database from blob file

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Have you looked into SSIS?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141204.aspx

Comment: Thanks for you reply!  I have seen this article before, but there is no info about how to move a database from one user's subscription to another user's subscription.

Comment: Oh so that only lets you change between your own subscriptions?  That makes sense only one account can be logged into the portal at a time.

Comment: Yes.  The person who own account A don't want to pay for it anymore, so I need to move it to account B, which is owned by another client.